# Can CDI be lessened towards Java SE?

Tags: java, dependency-injection, jakarta-ee, cdi, jboss-weld

JSR-330 dependency injection can be applied to both Java SE and Java EE environments, while JSR-299 is titled "Contexts and Dependency Injection for the Java EE platform".

Except strictly Java EE-oriented features, what CDI features make sense on Java SE as well? Any examples available? Thanks!

[Revised]
Here's [Weld on JSE.](http://docs.jboss.org/weld/reference/latest/en-US/html/environments.html#d0e5571)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Except strictly Java EE-oriented features, what CDI features make sense on Java SE as well? Any examples available? Thanks!

Well, the one mentioned in the Weld documentation:

> #### [18.4. Java SE](http://docs.jboss.org/weld/reference/latest/en-US/html/environments.html#d0e5571)
>
> In addition to improved integration of
>   the Enterprise Java stack, the
>   "Contexts and Dependency Injection for
>   the Java EE platform" specification
>   also defines a state of the art
>   typesafe, stateful dependency
>   injection framework, which can prove
>   useful in a wide range of application
>   types. To help developers take
>   advantage of this, Weld provides a
>   simple means for being executed in the
>   Java Standard Edition (SE) environment
>   independently of any Java EE APIs.
>
> When executing in the SE environment
>   the following features of Weld are
>   available:
>
> - Managed beans with @PostConstruct and @PreDestroy lifecycle callbacks
> - Dependency injection with qualifiers and alternatives
> - @Application, @Dependent and @Singleton scopes
> - Interceptors and decorators
> - Stereotypes
> - Events

This obviously makes sense in a Java SE context.

Answer (score 1):

see openwebbeans.apache.org